# can't fetch callback response in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, callback, jsonp

I am working on angularjs services. I got some callback response from my API endpoint. I am using angular jsonP to fetch callback response.i have attached my response below

```
projectInstance.jsonpCallback("getActiveProduct",{"totalRecords":null,"projectSnapShot":[{"projectId":"333333","projectNumber":"123456","projectStatus":"Active"}]})
```

here is my services function

```
getActiveProduct: function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();  
  var url ="myserver/getproject.json"

  $http.jsonp(url, {
    jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',
    data:''
  }).then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data.data);
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
    return deferred.reject(err);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

using these jsonp method i try to fetch my above response .But it throws console error like below

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: projectInstance is not defined
```

how to fetch my response .could anyone assist me for these issue?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that defines `projectInstance`? It seems to not be in scope (or not yet populated) when you call `projectInstance.jsonpCallback`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `deferred` how you have used it. `jsonp()` already returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The $http service already returns a promise. Managing the promise with your own $q.defer is bad. You can get rid of $q and just return data.

You service should also return that promise created by $http.

```
function getActiveProduct() {
  var url ="myserver/getproject.json"

  return $http.jsonp(url, {
    jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',
    data:''
  }).then(function(data){
    return data.data;
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
    return err;
  });
}
```

You can call this service this way:

```
myService.getActiveProduct().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: still i got **console.log**  like  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonpCallback' of null** .

Comment: @user3760261 did you in inject $http in your controller?

Comment: Yes I injected $http  inside my controller. In that service method i have used **jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback' ** but I got console error like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of null**  . Whatever value I gave to jsonpCallbackParams  It's shows console .log error like Cannot read the property .  Can you help me out this issue.